# Query in SQL Server, trying to merge two queries -- EDIT: Adding yet another query

Tags: sql-server, database, join, unions

I have this two queries:

```
SELECT localteam = teams.team_name from teams, games WHERE games.loc_team_number = teams.team_number

SELECT visitingteam = teams.team_name from teams, games WHERE games.vis_team_number = teams.team_number
```

And I'm trying to merge them but I just can't seem to get it right.
I'm trying this:

```
SELECT games.week, locteam, visteam, games.loc_goals, games.vis_goals
FROM games
JOIN (select locteam = teams.team_name from teams) AS locteam ON games.loc_team_number = teams.team_number
JOIN (select visteam = teams.team_name from teams) AS visteam ON games.vis_team_number = teams.team_number
```

But I get this error:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 118
The multi-part identifier "teams.team_number" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 119
The multi-part identifier "teams.team_number" could not be bound.

Each query works fine separately.

EDIT:

First answer got it right, thanks to anyone who replied

EDIT 2:

This answer did it:

```
SELECT games.week, locteam, visteam, games.loc_goals, games.vis_goals
FROM games
JOIN (select locteam = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS locteam ON games.loc_team_number = locteam.team_number
JOIN (select visteam = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS visteam ON games.vis_team_number = visteam.team_number
```

But if I wanted to add another field for the name of the team who won the game, would it be like this?:

```
SELECT games.week, locteam, visteam, games.loc_goals, games.vis_goals, winner
FROM games
JOIN (select locteam = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS locteam ON games.loc_team_number = locteam.team_number
JOIN (select visteam = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS visteam ON games.vis_team_number = visteam.team_number
JOIN (select winner = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS winner ON
```

I can't think of any condition that would work

Comment: Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Further advice:  edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `teams.team_number` requires a table or aliased table called `teams` and you don't have one . You only have `games`, `locteam` , `visteam`. replace teams with one of those three.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT games.week
     , locteam.team_name AS locteam 
     , visteam.team_name AS visteam 
     , games.loc_goals
     , games.vis_goals
FROM games 
LEFT JOIN teams AS locteam ON games.loc_team_number = locteam.team_number
LEFT JOIN teams AS visteam ON games.vis_team_number = visteam.team_number
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using an incorrect alias in the targets of your join. It should be:

```
SELECT games.week, locteam, visteam, games.loc_goals, games.vis_goals
FROM games
JOIN (select locteam = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS locteam ON games.loc_team_number = locteam.team_number
JOIN (select visteam = teams.team_name, team_number from teams) AS visteam ON games.vis_team_number = visteam.team_number
```

Note that I also took a guess that you have a `team_number` in your `teams` table and so I added it to the subqueries.